# Velux controller and input panel seem to communicate via a bus wire with a pull-up without resistor, how?

Tags: microcontroller, reverse-engineering, home-automation

I'm trying to replace a Velux input panel ([WLI 130](https://github.com/timdiels/velux_wli_130/tree/main/manuals)) with an ESP32 or Arduino so that I can automate the Velux windows by telling the ESP over wifi to open/close the windows. Before doing that I'm trying to make sense of how the panel communicates with the controller (probably a [WLC 100](https://github.com/timdiels/velux_wli_130/tree/main/manuals)) so I can replicate it on the microcontroller. I only have physical access to the panel, I found some manuals but nothing about the PCB or wire protocol.

My hypothesis about how they're communicating: There are 3 wires connecting the 2 devices; oddly yellow seems to be Vcc, red seems to be ground and blue is a signal wire. The signal wire is one-way communication from the panel to the controller. Multiple panels can be connected to the same controller on a bus. I've observed on the oscilloscope that both the controller and panel pull up the wire to ~5V when nothing is being transmitted. During transmission, the panel will cause the signal wire to jump between 5V and ground to send the bits.

What confuses me is that the controller does not seem to have a resistor on its pull up despite being an input pin; I accidentally measured 338 mA when connecting the controller signal pin to its ground pin. There seems to be an enhancing N-MOSFET on panel's PCB, I'm guessing that's used to briefly pull the signal wire to ground when transmitting, but if there was a resistor after the mosfet then the controller input pin would still read 5V, and if there is no resistor there, then how does it manage to only draw an average 0.75mA on the signal wire while transmitting a low? Is that possible or is there a flaw in my reasoning about how they're communicating or my interpretation of the measurements?

Full details: https://github.com/timdiels/velux_wli_130

Oscilloscope connected to the controller without the panel (blue = blue wire; yellow = yellow wire; ground = red wire). This shows that the controller pulls up the signal to 5V:

[image: WLC oscilloscope]

Oscilloscope connected to the panel connected to the controller while pressing a button. (It looks roughly the same when disconnecting the signal wire and measuring the signal pin on the panel; i.e. the panel also pulls up the signal to 5V). The lows here are 0V:

[image: WLI oscilloscope]

Oscilloscope across a 10 ohm resistor I added on the blue wire in between the controller and the panel (yellow is the voltage across resistor, blue is an overlay of the signal voltage so you can see how it overlaps). Transmitting a low averages 0.75mA. Transmitting high sees the current go back and forth a bit:

[image: WLI blue current]

Panel/WLI PCB:

[image: WLI PCB front]

Panel/WLI PCB (back side; mostly keyboard layout):

[image: WLI PCB back]

Panel/WLI case:

[image: WLI case]

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be using internal pull ups on the IC? Not sure if I understood the question though.

Comment: Is it possible that the signal wire has a pull down resistor and the MOSFET switches it high and then to signal the MOSFET is turned off allowing the signal to be pulled low by the resistor?

Comment: @Ralph The panel needs to send a command to the controller, so I'm expecting the controller to measure the voltage at its signal wire for input, but seems there's no resistor there because when I connect its signal and ground wire together I get 334mA. I could add a resistor on the panel-side (when replacing the panel with an Arduino) between signal and ground, when pulling it down for a command, but then the controller would still read 5V on the signal wire, wouldn't it? If I don't add the resistor, then it reads 0V but I'm frying the controller.

Comment: @GodJihyo I measure 5V across signal and ground both on the controller when it's not connected to the panel and on the panel when it's only connected to upstream power/ground. That's how I interpret the 2 oscilloscope images at least.

Comment: 334mA at 5V is what you'd expect with 15 ohms resistance, although I can't say if that's an actual resistor, circuit resistance or some current limit on the 5V. The manuals aren't much help. Perhaps it's using a current loop?

Comment: @Tim Diels, ok, then it's a keyboard matrix readout. That's what the routing looks like too. I'm still not understanding what you want to do? I'm guessing you want simulate pressing the buttons with some other circuit?

Comment: @Ralph I want to replace the panel entirely with an ESP32 which controls either an NPN transistor or an N-MOSFET on the signal wire in order to send commands to the controller/WLC that controls the motors of the velux windows, to open/close the windows. The ESP32 receives commands from home assistant over wifi to open/close the windows. It's just that normally you either have pull-up resistor on the controller input or a pull-down resistor on the panel/ESP output.

Comment: @GodJihyo I'll look into the current loop idea (current varies from 0.03mA in idle to an average 0.19mA when transmitting according to my multimeter), though it does not explain how when the panel and controller are fully connected, I manage to read 0V lows on the signal wire (see oscilloscope image), i.e. between controller and panel, unless the panel actually shorts it to ground but then I'd expect an average current of 34mA

Comment: Can you insert around 10 ohm in the blue wire path and connect the scope between blue and red on the panel side? This will help to estimate the current to GND during transmission.

Comment: @Jens I connected controller.blue -- 10 ohm -- oscilloscope.blue -- panel.blue and  panel.red -- oscilloscope.ground -- controller.ground but overlaying this with the signal without the resistor I see no different. Did you mean connecting the oscilloscope across just the resistor itself instead?

Comment: @Jens I added an image of the oscilloscope across the 10 ohm itself.